# One large array from multiple arrays Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I'v multiple *arrays* of `[1x3]`, however I named them `array1` `array2` `array3` and so on. What I want to create one array from all arrays such that `array=array1(i,1:3)` `array=array2(i,4:6)` and so on. How I can done this by looping or any suggestions regarding my approach, I actually want to access multiple arrays *dynamic* so that I'm going with this *approach*, any other suggestions are welcomed as I thought there will be slow computations and processing speed when my array size increases.

**My Code:**

```
  for i=1:10
    array(i)=array(:,i:i+3);
    end
```

Comment: for simplicity I reused `i` counter for such operation, it should be some other variable.

Comment: It's easier if, instead of using different variables, you store your arrays as different rows of a matrix

Comment: @LuisMendo and what about computations in loop? it affects or not?

Comment: @AhsanAli With my suggestion you could still use a loop, or you could avoid the loop. It would be much easier, just one line. Somethinkg like `array = reshape(array.',1,[]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is use `cat` function:

```
array = cat(2,array_1,array_2,array_3);
```

If you want to access array_i (i=1,2,3,...)

```
array_i = array((i-1)*3+1:i*3);
```

The `j`th index (j=1,2,3) of the `array_i` (i=1,2,3,4,...) can be accessed:

```
jth_index_of_array_i = array((i-1)*3+j)
```

Comment: what is `i` that you use? If you concatenate 1x3 arrays the resulting array would be 1x(3*number_of_arrays)

Comment: you said your array1, array2, ... are [1x3] then only number that `i` can have is 1.

Comment: Did you use the second option? Also, your initial arrays have to be [1x3].

Comment: why do you use `:`? `array` is a one dimensional array. Basically array_1 = array(1:3), array_2 = array(4:6) and so on...

Comment: Do the first line in my answer to concatenate all the arrays. If you want to access `array_1`, then do `array_1=array(1:3)`, for `array_2`, do `array_2=array(4:6)`, then for `array_i`, do `array_i=array((i-1)*3+1:i*3)`, replace `i` with whatever the number of array you want to access.

Comment: for the sake of simplicity, I'v  `array = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 4 5 6 7 8 9;]` now how to access `array(:,1:3)`  also couldn;t found correct result with `array_i=array((i-1)*3+1:i*3)`